# Closing a question claiming it's opinion based when it is not

Tags: discussion

I post this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/144178/9033) and in the footer I clearly stated:

> Please note, I'm not asking for an opinion. I'm asking which OS is more suitable to achieve my goals from a technical point of view (effort required, closer to my needs, etc...).

Hence, why my question <s>is going to be</s> was closed (without any explanation nor an hint to improve it) because "opinion based"?
Honestly I feel teased.

My question is pretty technical. What do i expect? An answer from a more experienced developer that can say: to reach your goals you need this and this, so this solution is recommended because requires less work. This other solution is not suitable because does not allow what you requires, etc...

To me, these are **not** opinions, are facts.

Of course, if I'm wrong, please help me to understand why and suggest how to improve the question.

Comment: The fact that you deleted the original question makes it impossible for anyone but mods and very high rep users to respond, see no one else besides the owner can see a deleted question.

Comment: @goldilocks the question was already closed

Comment: Yes, but you have posted here seeking a discussion of why it was closed ("please help me to understand why and suggest how to improve the question").  Anyone, including the five regular users who closed the question, can read a closed question.  **Practically no one can read a deleted one** (we only have 16 users with enough rep, 3 of whom are mods as well, and only 6-7 of which are regularly active), so you have short circuited any discussion that might have happened...

Comment: @goldilocks no problem. I've undeleted it. For experience when I ask questions like this on meta I get a lot of downvotes without any discussion, hence I deleted the question.

Answer (score 3):

The major problem I see with this is that, while you may not realize it, the only criteria in that post that isn't a matter of opinion is WRT mounting the SD card read-only, since I believe there are some distros that specialize in this.

The other things, such as software availability, are going to be the same regardless of distro, although some of them offer more recent versions than others as a matter of policy (eg. RpiOS/Raspbian, being derived from Debian, tends to have slightly older versions than Ubuntu or Fedora; this is a conservative approach I believe intended for stability).

How easy software is to configure is largely a matter of opinion too, and you have a fairly diverse list, meaning anyone who wants to cover that at a level of detail beyond a casual opinion is going to have to write a lot of words.  Also, in general configuring stuff like Apache, MariaDB, etc., is pretty much the same everywhere.

All that said, over time the general sentiment here is that the most appropriate distro to recommend is RpiOS for a number of objective reasons (albeit, ones that weren't on your list):

- It's maintained by the Pi Foundation and therefore will tend to lead the pack in terms of bug fixes, new feature interfaces, etc.  It's also documented by them to some extent.
- If this place is any indication, it's the choice of the majority of Pi users, meaning it has the largest community support.  This can be very significant eg., for young new users unfamiliar with linux, because if you aren't using RpiOS you are going to end up on your own with certain problems, or find following on-line tutorials etc. more difficult.

I think these things are particularly pertinent in context here (donation to a school).

Finally, a quick word about:

> I remember it was not so easy to make a working read-only file-system.

That hasn't really changed as far as I can tell, although it isn't something I've ever bothered with.  I recommend you don't, either.  It will create many more problems than it solves.  It won't necessarily solve your corruption issue either, as people running read-only systems have posted here it still can happen when the power gets yanked.  I'd guess this maybe to do with whatever weird voltage fluctuations accompany that.

The consensus here is that it isn't nearly a big a problem as it is made out to be anyone; many of the long term users including myself would observe that they've probably had the power cut, or pulled the plug, dozens or hundreds of times but rarely if ever has that led to something the `fsck` on reboot can't handle.  It is probably much more likely if the power goes during a period of very intense writing to the card, and very unlikely if the system is mostly idle.

Comment: I get your general point, but I honestly don't agree on them all. For example: "How easy software is to configure is largely a matter of opinion too". Not at all: changing a setting in a config file *is* easier than follow a procedure of hundreds of steps. Or downloading a package *is* easier than compile a large application and its dependencies from sources. These are facts to me, not opinions. Do you agree?

Comment: Just a clarification: "(donation to a school)" perhaps I wasn't able to explain it well. I would donate a finished product (think a about a digital signage). They have just to plug in the power. I said I write the application, not they.

Comment: I suppose I meant configuring *the same* software.  So while it might make sense to ask, "What is the easier SQL database to configure, ___, ____, or ____?" as there are certainly significant objective issues that could be considered, asking, "Which distro makes PostgreSQL easiest to use?" is going to mostly be about people endorsing their preferred distro because it is the most familiar to them.  But if you look seriously at that, configuring PostgreSQL is going to be more or less identical everywhere.